# Better way to split a binary in chunks, preferably with bitstring comprehensions

Tags: erlang, list-comprehension, bitstring

I'm trying to replace the following function with something more elegant:

```
split_packet(_, <<>>) ->
    [];
split_packet(Size, P) when byte_size(P) < Size ->
    [ P ];
split_packet(Size, P) ->
    {Chunk, Rest} = split_binary(P, Size),
    [ Chunk | split_packet(Size, Rest) ].
```

(I now this is not tail recursive -- wanted to keep it simple, besides it does not matter performance wise in newer Erlang versions)

Example output:

```
1> split_packet(3, <<1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8>>).
[<<1,2,3>>,<<4,5,6>>,<<7,8>>]
```

A elegant solution with list comprehensions would be preferable since the result of this is further processed with a list-comprehension which could then be wrapped in one comprehension.

I tried

```
[ X || <<X:Size/binary>> <= P ].
```

but this leaves off the last chunk if the Size is not a multiple of `byte_site(P)`:

```
2>  [ X || <<X:3/binary>> <= <<1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8>> ].
[<<1,2,3>>,<<4,5,6>>]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frankly, I don't see much wrong with your current version. As you state, you can't do it with a binary/list comprehension because the last fragment will be discarded.

The only thing I can think of is reordering the clauses to match the most frequent case first:

```
split_packet(Size, P) when byte_size(P) >= Size->
    {Chunk, Rest} = split_binary(P, Size),
    [Chunk|split_packet(Size, Rest)];
split_packet(_Size, <<>>) ->
    [];
split_packet(_Size, P)  ->
    [P].
```

Comment: OK, thanks.  I had hoped a nice trick with binary matching that escaped me could make a nice one liner out of it.

Comment: The `Size` argument in the last `split_packet/2` declaration isn't used, so it should be replaced with `_` or prepended with `_`.

Comment: @KristinnÖrnSigurðsson Thanks, I cleaned it up a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly pad the input binary with `(Size - (byte_size(Binary) rem Size)) * 8` , run it thru your list comprehension `[ X || <<X:Size/binary>> <= P ]`

`Y = (Size - (byte_size(Binary) rem Size)) * 8`

`[ X || << X:3/binary >> <= << Binary/binary , 0:Y >> ]`

And then chop the extra bits from the last segment..

Comment: Workarounds like this somehow defeat the reason for the list comprehension -- elegance and shortness, and it'll be slower to first pad the binary and chop it off the last chunk.  Besides I'd rather do `{A, R} = split_binary(byte_size(P) div Size) * Size), [ X || <<X:Size/binary>> <= A ] ++ R` but don't consider this as elegant.  Especially since I can't have the other operations I need to do on the chunks in the same comprehension since I need special handling of the last chunk then.

Answer (score 2):

A variation of your original that might be a little more efficient:

```
split_packet(Size, Data) when Size > 0 ->
    case Data of
        <<Packet:Size/binary, Rest/binary>> ->
            [Packet | split_packet(Size, Rest)];
        <<>> ->
            [];
        _ ->
            [Data]
    end.
```